# javascript function to show current date and time on click of Clear

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

When i load a JSP page ,i have date and TimeTextBox with current date and time displayed and other form elements like drop down menu,textbox,textarea. I have written a javascript function to clear the form elements. Issue is when i click on "CLEAR" button, the date and TimeTextbox should show current date and Time, at present all fields are becoming blank.
My javascript function is as below:

```
function clearForm()
 {
     document.getElementById("Country").selectedIndex = 0;
     document.getElementById('State').options.length = 0;
     document.getElementById('PATH').value="";
     $("textarea").val("");
     $("input[type=hidden]").val("");
     return false;
 }
```

Below is the jsp code for Date and TimeTextbox, they were created using DOJO.

```
    SELECT DATE AND TIME : <input name="TIME_SCHEDULE" id="oracle" value="${data.currentDate}" required="true"/>  
     <input id="time" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" onChange="require(['dojo/dom'], function(dom){dom.byId('val').value=dom.byId('time1').value.toString().replace(/.*1970\s(\S+).*/,'T$1')})"
        required="true" />
...
<button name="clearButton" id="clearButton" onclick="return clearForm()">CLEAR</button>
```

By default when i open the form , it shows current date and time, once i select different date and time and click on clear button, i want date and TimeTextbox to show recent date and time.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the clearButton the clearForm gets executed.

```
 onclick="return clearForm()"
```

And in your clearForm() function you have initialized them to blank ("") as can be seen below.

```
$("textarea").val("");
$("input[type=hidden]").val("");
```

If you want recent date and time you need to call the Date() function, something like this.

```
$("textarea").val(new Date());
```